# After uploading the files, what shall I do in order to display their output on the web page?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, crud, pythonanywhere

I am creating a CRUD web app using python and flask.

Here is the link to see the output:
http://zcds4327.pythonanywhere.com/

Here is the repository's link:
https://github.com/OCTRACORE/cs_proj_pro_1

**Tree structure:**

```
.
├── Password_creator.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── Password_creator.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── exec_prog.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── global_data.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── table.cpython-38.pyc
├── exec_prog.py
├── global_data.py
├── passwd_file
├── requirements.txt
├── start.sh
├── static
│   ├── AddPasswdInp.css
│   ├── dispManipMenu.css
│   ├── favicon_io
│   │   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── site.webmanifest
│   ├── input.css
│   ├── show.css
│   └── showOutput.css
├── table.py
└── template
    ├── add.html
    ├── file-manip.html
    ├── input.html
    ├── modify.html
    ├── output_disp.html
    ├── semantic-error.html
    └── str_main.html
```

`Parent directory of the code:cs_proj_pro_1`

**Code snippet (from the file exec_prog.py):**

```
@app.route('/generate/file-manip-upload',methods = ["GET","POST"])
def upload_file(): #for uploading the file

  decrypted_pass_output_lst = []
  decrypted_desc_output_lst = []
  decrypted_password = []
  decrypted_data = ""
  Upload_key = "" #for storing the key

  if request.method == "POST":
    Uploadpassfile= request.files['Uploadpassfile'] #requesting the name of the required file
    Uploadpassfile_name = secure_filename(Uploadpassfile.filename) #storing the name of the password saving file
    Uploadkeyfile = request.files['Uploadkeyfile'] #requesting the name of the key storing file
    Uploadkeyfile_name = secure_filename(Uploadkeyfile.filename) #storing the name of the key storing file
    descfileUpload = request.files['descfileUpload'] #requesting the name of the file storing descriptions
    descfileUpload_name = secure_filename(descfileUpload.filename) #storing the name of the file string descriptions
  #print(Uploadkeyfile_name,Uploadpassfile_name,descfileUpload_name)
   
    with open(Uploadkeyfile_name,"rb") as k: # reading the containing the key
      Upload_key = k.read()
    key_init_sec = Fernet(Upload_key)

    with open(Uploadpassfile_name,"rb") as k: # reading the file containing the passwords by decrypting them
       for i in k:
         decrypted_pass_output_lst.append(str(key_init_sec.decrypt(i),encoding="utf-8"))

    with open(descfileUpload_name,"rb") as k: #reading the file containing the descriptions by decrypting them
        for i in k:
          decrypted_desc_output_lst.append(str(key_init_sec.decrypt(i),encoding="utf-8"))

  x = len(decrypted_pass_output_lst)
  (GlobalData.password).clear() #clearing the GlobalData.password list to avoid piling up of data
  for s in range(x): #for inserting the decrypted data inside the GlobalData.password list for display
        data_decrypted = Table(decrypted_pass_output_lst[s],decrypted_desc_output_lst[s])
        (GlobalData.password).append(data_decrypted)
```

**Working directory:**

```
/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1
```

**Environment used:**
PythonAnywhere

When I try to save the passwords and their corresponding descriptions, I need to go to the file manipulation page by clicking on the `save/upload` **/** `upload/save` link present at the home page and output page respectively.

The routes of the pages are:

1.) http://zcds4327.pythonanywhere.com/generate/file-manip-disp

2.) http://zcds4327.pythonanywhere.com/generate/show-output

After that, I have to select three files from the local machine. One file will be used for storing the passwords by encrypting them. The other one will store the description of all the passwords by encrypting them. The third one will store the key used for encrypting both the files. After that, I have to click the submit button to save them.

The files finally get stored inside the `ZCDS4327` folder.

To show the outputs again in the web app in the decrypted way I have to select the files containing the required data through the `uploading section of the page through the required buttons, then click on submit to receive the output.

I have created a virtual environment in my local machine which runs a replica of this program inside the `localhost` server.  If I try to upload all the three files which have contents from the app hosted by the `localhost` server to the app hosted by the **pythonanywhere** server, I receive an internal server error. My aim is that the user is able to upload the files from whichever part of their system they want.

**The error log**

```
2020-10-07 08:47:16,087: Exception on /generate/file-manip-upload [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ZCDS4327/proj/cs_proj_pro_1/exec_prog.py", line 155, in upload_file
    with open(Uploadkeyfile_name,"rb") as k: # reading the containing the key
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keyfile.txt'
```

*Here, I am the user as well as the developer.*

So what shall I do in order to resolve this error? Every suggestion will be appreciated.

**Notes:**

***The localhost server has been taken as an example. The problem, as I believe will be encountered in the case of any other server too.***

***The files saved by the user will get downloaded to their system. The code for that is not yet written and I do not think that in this case, it is required to know that.***

Comment: Can you please add the code snippet(s) that generate the error. You can't expect us to dig through your repository to find the relevant files and snippets. Thx. :)

Comment: I have added the required code snippet. You can refer to the file ''exec_prog.py''  for some more details.

Comment: You say that you get an internal server error on PythonAnywhere -- if you look at the website's error log (linked from the "Web" page) then you'll see a stack trace at the bottom of the file showing what the most recent error was caused by.  That might be enough for you to fix the problem yourself, but if not, it would be useful information for you to add to your post here.

Comment: I have added the information from the error log. It shows '' No such file or directory: 'keyfile.txt' "

Comment: That means that 'keyfile.txt' is not in the working directory and, from your directory tree, it does not exist. Your code gives no indication of where 'keyfile.txt' is supposed to come from, so your first debugging step is to work out why the file is not where you expect it to be.

Comment: So you mean I have to locate the selected file to the working directory and then perform the required actions?

Comment: You can do that, or you can use a full path to specify the file -- one starting with `/`, like `/home/yourusername/somedirectory/keyfile.txt`.

Comment: @GilesThomas this works. Now, I am able to carry out the task properly.